# How do I edit Minecraft Mod Class files?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to edit a single line in Pam's Harvestcraft mod. The reason is that in the game these "gardens" inside the mod spawn too often. There is a config file for this mod, however the lowest possible value for rarity = 1 is still too high. This rarity is an int, and I want to change it to a float inside this Mod's jar's .class file, so that I may be able to use 0.5 or something less than 1 to decrease the chance of these gardens spawning.

I copy and pasted the .class file into intelliJ, but it is readable only. Writing my own text file and changing the extension to .class obviously corrupts the file.

For the past hour I've been trying to Google the answer. People say that you might need to set up a modding environment, decompile the code, then recompile it after the changes. This seems very long-winded for a simple line of code editing.

Edit: I haven't figured it out yet. Something to add: I downloaded this class file editor http://dirty-joe.com/
It let's me edit the field with the int to float. However there are 2 problems with this;

1, I also need to edit a method that getInt() to getFloat() which I cannot do.

2, When I save the newly edited class file, then try to reopen it using this JOE editor IT IS GIVING ME A FILE ERROR. This indicated to me that if I edit the class file it corrupts it anyways.

Comment: If it is a compiled .class file, there is a reason for that. I would not do it, or look into the API for the file and then develop something out of that.

Comment: Changing a variable type, as simple as it seems (may not be as simple depending on how the value is handled internally in the code), will indeed require recompiling the code in a strongly typed language such as Java. If you're interested in this you'll need to look into setting up a development env for the mod, decompiling and recompiling the code back. Note this is prone to cause side effects and unexpected errors as decompiled source will not always be verbatim. Requesting the mod dev to do the change, and asking for the sources and/or help setting up an environment could make things easier.

Comment: Plus, manually editing a class file is definitely not the way to go, .class is an unreadable/uneditable format by design - by humans at least. Edit the source (decompiled if not available) and compile it back again.

Comment: Instead of attempting to modify the class file, perhaps you can extend it or create your own class which periodically updates the `rarity` value from 1 to 0, or 0 to 1.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Ocelot and thanks for the explanation Xavi. I'm gonna look into editing the mods. 

Andrew, that's an interesting idea too. Might check that out too if I can't edit the mod itself. I don't want to change anything regarding the tickrate or any base files of Minecraft, but your idea might work swapping the rarity between 0 and 1. This garden generation all happens at world generation though, so it's probably just instant. I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe you could create a [script](https://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/2-3-5-known-bugs-and-fixes-for-them.141664/#post-1561114) that somehow intercepts. (This link isn't exactly what you could do, but it gives an overview that something like this *might* be possible). Or as an alternative, you could contact the developer [Pam](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/pams-harvestcraft) herself. HarvestCraft still seems to be actively developed so there might be a chance she'll consider your change request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You technically can do this, but it's going to be a pain. If it were just changing a variable, that might be simple, but now you're also talking about changing a field's type.

There are a couple ways to do this, and I don't see one of them listed, so I'll mention that.

First, you can decompile/recompile. I've tried doing this once before, and it really doesn't work well. There were plenty of errors resulting from the recompilation, because it's not going to be a completely accurate decompilation.

The second option, and this would be the easiest if not for needing to change a field type, is editing the machine code. Java is compiled into assembly code that is specifically used by the JVM. You would find the instruction, change the value, and you would be golden. (I say easiest, but if you've never seen assembly before, it'll all look like Greek to you.)

Back to the issue: You're talking about changing a data type. That won't be enough. You not only would need to change the data type, but *every spot* that data type is used and its `get` method is called. Every spot that getter is called, its expecting an int return value. If it's a `float` going into an `int`, it'll just be automatically converted to an `int`.

So that is how you would do it, but it's not really worth your time. Simply ask the developer to make an update for you. In fact, if [this](https://github.com/MatrexsVigil/harvestcraft) is the mod you're talking about, it's already open source and you can make the changes yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely well typed suggestion Christopher.

I managed to edit the file using a random editor (mentioned it above in my original post) and I also realized that I need to update the getInt() to getFloat() as you cleverly suggested. I'm not a 100% sure but it might just be these 2 fields I have to edit. The problem is, as I wrote I think that this random editor might just corrupt the original file, not sure.


This is the [mod](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/pams-harvestcraft]) in question. The creator only gives the source code to paying Patreon members.

Comment: I was going to decompile, change and then recompile the code, but if you say it corrupts the file I might just leave it. Such a shame. I wonder if I can create my own Mod to overwrite this field. Thanks!

Comment: My mistake, the mod is open source for Version 1.12.2.
However I would need 1.10.2 from her which I think is only available to paid Patreon members.

Comment: Just another idea I had: Instead of converting it to a float, which may have a lot of side effects, find out where the chance of spawning is calculated and increase that number. For instance, if the chance is `x/10`, simply change it to `x/100`. That would allow you to more finely tune the value.

Answer (score 2):

Go make an issue or Pull Request on [HarvestCraft's GitHub page](https://github.com/MatrexsVigil/harvestcraft).

Alternatively, you can download the source from there, make the change, and compile up a version that you can use for yourself. You, of course, will have to set up a Forge development environment to do this, but that isn't very hard either:

1. Go to Forge's [download page](http://files.minecraftforge.net/)
2. Download the MDK for the appropriate version of Minecraft
3. Unzip into a directory
4. Run `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` and `gradlew setupEclipse` from the command line in this directory
5. Download and install [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/)
6. Add HarvestCraft's src directory to the Forge src directory (so that the contents of the one ends up in the other `Forge/src/java`, not `Forge/src/src/java`).
7. Run Eclipse, tell it to open an existing workspace, point it at where you installed Forge.
8. Make your changes
9. Run `gradlew build`
10. Get the resulting jar from `Forge/builds/lib`